# Fatal error: while loading codeigniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using a function from codeigniter controller which calls a model called payment plan for me to use. I have been using this method all over the place but this is the first time I am getting a problem with it. The error is 
`Fatal error: Call to a member function createPaymentPlan() on a non-object in`
I am not sure what I am doing wrong but here is the code.

```
            $this->load->model("payment_plan");
            $this->load->model("fee_page");

            foreach ($itemdetails as $itemdetail) {
                $Amount = $itemdetail["borrowOrInvestAmount"];
                $currency = $itemdetail["Currency"];
                $Interest = $itemdetail["Interest"];
                $Loantime = (isset($data['Loantime']) && $data['Loantime'] > 0) ? $data['Loantime'] : $itemdetail["Loantime"];
                $start_date = $data["start_date"];
                $payment_term = $data["payment_term"];                   

                $paymenPlanSingle = $this->payment_plan->createPaymentPlan($Amount, $currency, $Interest, $Loantime, $start_date, $payment_term);
                $countOfElements = count($paymenPlanSingle);
             }
```

The second it reaches payment_plan it crashes even though I loaded the controller already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks okay. Most of the time this problem is occurs due to a loading of controller before. Check if you are loading any controller before or not, if you are, please load the model `"payment_plan"` before it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the controller does not overwrite var

```
$this->payment_plan
```

if you can show the controller and model payment_plan